# Решите проблему с задачей очередь с защитой от ошибок

Tags: python

я писал подобное обращение, но я в заблуждении, так как с стеком и деком решил, а тут ничего не помогает

> Очередь с защитой от ошибок
>
> Реализуйте структуру данных "очередь". Напишите программу, содержащую
> описание очереди и моделирующую работу очереди, реализовав все
> указанные здесь методы. Программа считывает последовательность команд
> и в зависимости от команды выполняет ту или иную операцию. После
> выполнения каждой команды программа должна вывести одну строчку.
> Возможные команды для программы:
>
> - push n — добавить в очередь число n (значение n задаётся после команды). Программа должна вывести ok;
> - pop — удалить из очереди первый элемент. Программа должна вывести его значение;
> - front — программа должна вывести значение первого элемента, не удаляя его из очереди;
> - size — программа должна вывести количество элементов в очереди;
> - clear — программа должна очистить очередь и вывести ok;
> - exit — программа должна вывести bye и завершить работу.
>
> Перед исполнением операций front и pop программа должна проверять,
> содержится ли в очереди хотя бы один элемент. Если во входных данных
> встречается операция front или pop и при этом очередь пуста, то
> программа должна вместо числового значения вывести строку error.
>
> ввод:
>
> ```
> push 1
> front
> exit
> ```
>
> вывод:
>
> ```
> ok
> 1
> bye
> ```

вот код

```
def push(a,n):
    a.append(n)
    print('ok')

def pop(a):
    if len(a)>0:
        print(a.pop([0]))
    else:
        print('error')

def front(a):
    if len(a)>0:
        print(a[0])
    else:
        print('error')
    
def size(a):
    print(len(a))

def clear(a):
    a.clear()
    print('ok')
a=[]
word=list(iter(input, 'exit'))

for i in word:
    if 'size' in i:
        size(a)
    elif 'pop' in i:
        pop(a)
    elif 'front' in i:
        front(a)
    elif 'clear' in i:
        clear(a)
    else:        
        push(a,i.split()[-1])
    
print('bye')
```

конкретно не проходит тесты
, прошу помощи

Comment: Этот вопрос тут раз в несколько дней задают. Вы бы поиском воспользовались, на него уже несколько раз отвечали. А так у вас очень странная конструкция `word=list(iter(input, 'exit'))` - это вообще что такое?

Comment: идите учиться. на сколько я помню вам эту задачу ставит интервьер. неужели вы считаете что работать будете за счет наших ответов? задача элементарная, а судя по коду вы даже на джуна не тянете. `a.pop([0])` - кто вам сказал что это так работает?

Comment: У меня a.pop([0]) работает только в другой программе конкретно в стеке такой же код и он прошел

Comment: Где word ввод там тоже работает всё, но в другой задаче

Comment: Она схожа с этой

Comment: Не нужно так оскорбительно, я прошу объяснить что не так интересно ведь

Comment: У нас кстати в курсах так и написано использовать a.pop

Comment: https://pythonz.net/references/named/list.pop/

Comment: `[i]` означает что это элемент под индексом `i`. Посмотрите примеры, там пишется без `[]`

Comment: это у меня уже конкретно сюда так скопировалось, извините

Comment: афигеть можно, я ее решил спустя неделю

Answer (score 0):

У тебя по времени не проходит или ответы неверные? Ты подумал про то, что все операции для очереди должны быть за О(1)? Твое >a.pop([0])< будет работать за О(n). Предлагаю вариант: смещать индекс первого элемента очереди, не производя других операций. Также не забудь подумать про лишнее место в массиве, которое будет забито уже "удаленными" элементами. Другие команды также придется немного изменить, но это будет быстрее.

Answer (score 0):

Идея такая же, как у ответа выше. В тестирующей системе Сириуса проходит все тесты.

```
command = 0
index_first = 0
queue = []
while command != 'exit':
    command = input()
    if 'push' in command:
        if len(queue) - index_first <= index_first:
            queue = queue[index_first:]
            index_first = 0
        queue.append(int(command.split()[-1]))
        print('ok')
    elif command == 'pop':
        if len(queue) - index_first > 0:
            print(queue[index_first])
            index_first += 1
        else:
            print('error')
    elif command == 'front':
        print(queue[index_first]) if len(queue) - index_first > 0 else print('error')
    elif command == 'size':
        print(len(queue) - index_first)
    elif command == 'clear':
        queue = []
        index_first = 0
        print('ok')
    elif command == 'exit':
        print('bye')
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]